# Insecure connection when trying to access a web server

Tags: php, http, post, jqgrid

I have a web server on which I have put a php script to retrieve post data for jqgrid. It has been working fine until a week ago when the router changed. When I tried to access the script in the browser it shows an insecure connection:

http://202.137.141.245/tokoweblink/weblink.php?q=1&rows=10&page=1

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before?

Comment: It's your certificate: `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`. That may be caused for various reasons.... Can you elaborate what PHP code you are trying to run?

Comment: ^ That means that your website could not prove it is what is says it is based on its own authority.

Comment: Here is the code:
https://pastebin.com/dWUkkvxS

It worked fine before the router changed though, but I could did not see that the new router has set a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You'll see this error when Chrome stops because the page tried to redirect you too many times.
Sometimes, pages don't open because cookies aren't working correctly.To fix the error, trying clearing your cookies.

Click on Settings > Show Advanced Settings…
Now in privacy section, click on Content Settings…
Content setting popup will appear, in Cookies click on All Cookies and Site Data…
In Search cookies, type the website for which you wish to remove cookies and then click on “Delete this Item” button to remove cookies.